# Analytic Elements Haag-Araki theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, time, analyticity

Why the elements of a local von Neumann algebra cannot be analytic elements of the timelike translation?

[image]

Comment: Could you please state the definition of analytic element with respect to timelike translations?

Comment: The definition is as found in Brattelli Robinson I:

Comment: I cannot check it now, but I guess that $X$ is the local von Neumann algebra and the indicated topology is one of the natural weak topologies interesting for von Neumann algebras. I think that one is also assuming some spectral condition on the representation of the group of four-translations implying that the generator of time displacements is bounded below. I expect that this asymmetry is responsible for the lack of analiticy in any set of the form $I_\lambda$.

Comment: Yes, you are right! The question is about whether one, given the usual axioms of a Haag - Araki theory (Isotony, weak additivity, Poincare Covariance, Microcausality, Spectrum Condition) can think of an analytic element as belonging in a local algebra associated with an open bounded region, say, a double cone.

Comment: In general, X is the global von Neumann Algebra, so as to have the unitary implementation of the translations. However, can we consider the observable to belong in a local algebra?

Comment: So there is a strongly continuous representation of time displacement whose generator is bounded below. Referring to the spectral decomposition of that operator and computing the expectation value implicit in your analyticity condition you should be able to prove the claim. Without details I cannot say more. Maybe a proof of your statement can be found in a book by Borchers published by Springer...The last book by Borchers I think. Sorry I do not remember the title.

Comment: Yes at $t=0$ the observable belongs to a local algebra, but it does not for large $t$ since the orbits of time translations are not bounded...

Comment: The last chapter of this book https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783662140789

Comment: Thank you, I am checking it right now. Why do you say that for t=0, the observable is local?

Comment: Simply you can assume it!